# Creating a percentage column on a table made from an inner join

Tags: mysql, select, count, aggregate-functions, percentage

I have two tables Orders and RMA. I wrote this command to return an inner join between the two tables. OrderID is the primary key of Orders and foreign key of RMA.

```
SELECT Orders.SKU, COUNT(*) AS Frequency
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN RMA ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.SKU
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This select statement returns a table with one column containing SKU values and one column containing the number of times each SKU value appears in the data. My goal is to create a third column that includes a percent that represents the frequency of each SKU value.

(disclaimer: I'm new to mysql, so if there's more information needed for this question, I am happy to provide it. Thanks!)

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You must divide `COUNT(*)` with the total number of rows in `RMA`:

```
SELECT Orders.SKU, 
       COUNT(*) AS Frequency,
       COUNT(*) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RMA) AS percent
FROM Orders INNER JOIN RMA 
ON Orders.OrderID = RMA.OrderID
GROUP BY Orders.SKU
ORDER BY Frequency DESC;
```

Comment: @yellowephant fine if it worked and don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: Note that this is a ratio, not a percentage